# Calling CXF client from jsp for https is getting org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException

Tags: java, cxf, cxfrs, cxf-client, jax-ws-customization

I am using JBoss 5.1 GA server and configured SSL in server.xml like below. Calling my CXF client from jsp is getting  the below error:

```
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
```

Please help me to resolve this error. One more thing is that the same war is successfully working in tomcat 7 server.

SSL configuration in server.xml:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
           port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
           scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
           keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/mykeystore.jks"
           keystorePass="q1234" sslProtocol = "TLSv1" />
```

My client code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",JksfilePath); 
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",password);  
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",JksfilePath);
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",password);

RequestTransmitterService ss = new RequestTransmitterService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
RequestTransmitterPortType port = ss.getRequestTransmitterPort(new AddressingFeature(false));  

BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider)port;
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(
                             "set-jaxb-validation-event-handler",
                             "false");
provider.getRequestContext().put(
                     BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                     "https://test.state.us/dev/TransService");

port.RequestTransmitter(RequestTransmitter,
                        l_HeaderRequestType,
                        l_objTrnsmtReqDtlType);
```

My war libs:

```
activemq-broker-5.9.1.jar
activemq-client-5.9.1.jar
activemq-openwire-legacy-5.9.1.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
commons-codec-1.10.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
cxf-core-3.0.4.jar
cxf-manifest.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-coloc-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-corba-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-object-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-bindings-xml-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-aegis-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-jibx-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-sdo-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-databinding-xmlbeans-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-features-clustering-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-js-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-javascript-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-management-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-rs-client-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-rs-extension-search-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-rs-security-cors-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-rs-security-jose-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-rs-security-oauth-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-rs-security-oauth2-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-rs-security-sso-saml-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-rs-security-xml-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-rs-service-description-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-security-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-hc-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-transports-http-netty-client-3.0

cxf-rt-transports-http-netty-server-3.0

cxf-rt-transports-jms-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-transports-local-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-transports-udp-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-ws-mex-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-ws-policy-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-ws-rm-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-ws-security-3.0.4.jar
cxf-rt-wsdl-3.0.4.jar
cxf-services-sts-core-3.0.4.jar
cxf-services-ws-discovery-api-3.0.4.jar
cxf-services-ws-discovery-service-3.0.4

cxf-services-wsn-api-3.0.4.jar
cxf-services-wsn-core-3.0.4.jar
cxf-tools-common-3.0.4.jar
cxf-tools-corba-3.0.4.jar
cxf-tools-java2ws-3.0.4.jar
cxf-tools-misctools-3.0.4.jar
cxf-tools-validator-3.0.4.jar
cxf-tools-wadlto-jaxrs-3.0.4.jar
cxf-tools-wsdlto-core-3.0.4.jar
cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb-3.0.4

cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-javascript-3.

cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws-3.0.4.j

cxf-xjc-boolean-3.0.2.jar
cxf-xjc-bug671-3.0.2.jar
cxf-xjc-dv-3.0.2.jar
cxf-xjc-javadoc-3.0.2.jar
cxf-xjc-runtime-3.0.2.jar
cxf-xjc-ts-3.0.2.jar
ehcache-2.8.5.jar
endorsed
FastInfoset-1.2.13.jar
geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1

geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar
geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.2.jar
geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
hawtbuf-1.9.jar
httpasyncclient-4.0.2.jar
httpclient-4.3.5.jar
httpcore-4.3.3.jar
httpcore-nio-4.3.3.jar
integration
jasypt-1.9.2.jar
java-json.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar
jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar
jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar
jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.9.jar
jettison-1.3.7.jar
jetty-continuation-8.1.15.v20140411.jar
jetty-http-8.1.15.v20140411.jar
jetty-io-8.1.15.v20140411.jar
jetty-security-8.1.15.v20140411.jar
jetty-server-8.1.15.v20140411.jar
jetty-util-8.1.15.v20140411.jar
joda-time-2.2.jar
js-1.7R2.jar
mina-core-2.0.9.jar
neethi-3.0.3.jar
oauth-20100527.jar
oauth-provider-20100527.jar
opensaml-2.6.1.jar
openws-1.5.1.jar
org.apache.commons.httpclient.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar
slf4j-jdk14-1.7.9.jar
spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
stax2-api-3.1.4.jar
velocity-1.7.jar
WHICH_JARS
woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar
wss4j-bindings-2.0.3.jar
wss4j-policy-2.0.3.jar
wss4j-ws-security-common-2.0.3.jar
wss4j-ws-security-dom-2.0.3.jar
wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax-2.0.3.jar
wss4j-ws-security-stax-2.0.3.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar
xmlsec-2.0.3.jar
xmltooling-1.4.1.jar
```

my web.xml-> Since I am directly calling from jsp, I put web.xml as empty like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>   
</web-app>
```